Vertical viewport was given unbounded height error while using nested scrollable widgets
I was trying to implement infinite scrolling with  this package  but since the PagedMasonryGridView is inside ListView its throws 'Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
' error even though i set shrinkWrap property on the PagedMasonryGridView to true. whats the solution for this?
body: ListView(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Stack(
                  alignment: const Alignment(0, 1.25),
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: Get.width,
                      height: Get.height * 0.35,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: context.theme.colorScheme.primary,
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(8),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text.rich(
                          TextSpan(
                            text: "discover".tr,
                            style: Get.textTheme.headlineLarge!.copyWith(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                            ),
                            children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                text: "localBusiness".tr + "!",
                                style: Get.textTheme.headlineLarge!.copyWith(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Positioned(
                      child: HomePageSearchPlaceHolder(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: Get.height * 0.06),
                const Divider(thickness: .1),
                SizedBox(height: Get.height * 0.02),
                Obx(() {
                  if (controller.isCategoryLoading.isTrue) {
                    return CategoryShimmerGrid();
                  } else if (controller.categories.value.isEmpty &&
                      homeWrapperController.index.value == 0) {
                    return RNotFound(label: "No Category Found!");
                  } else if (controller.categories.value.isNotEmpty)
                    return CategoryItemsGrid();
                  return SizedBox();
                }),
                SizedBox(height: Get.height * 0.02),
                const Divider(thickness: .1),
                SizedBox(height: Get.height * 0.02),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          PagedMasonryGridView.count(
            crossAxisSpacing: 8,
            mainAxisSpacing: 8,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            pagingController: controller.pagingController,
            builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<BusinessModel>(
              newPageProgressIndicatorBuilder: (_) => RLoading(),
              firstPageProgressIndicatorBuilder: (_) => RLoading(),
              animateTransitions: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, business, index) {
                return RBusinessContainer(business: business);
              },
            ),
            crossAxisCount: 2,
          ),
        ],
      ),

as you can see here the PagedMsontryGrid's shrinkWrap is set to true but the error still persists. it works fine with MasonryGridView.builder.
